# Flask Babel - 'translations/de/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po' is marked as fuzzy, skipping

Tags: python, flask, python-babel

I cant get a basic translationto work in Flask Babel.

Here are my steps.

1. I have this in a page `{{_("Hello")}}`
2. I run this command.

   ```
   pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -o messages.pot .
   ```
3. I then run this command for German.

   ```
   pybabel init -i messages.pot -d translations -l de
   ```
4. Here is the mo file for german in `/app/translations/de/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po`

   ```
   # German translations for PROJECT.
   # Copyright (C) 2012 ORGANIZATION
   # This file is distributed under the same license as the PROJECT project.
   # FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, 2012.
   #
   #, fuzzy
   msgid ""
   msgstr ""
   "Project-Id-Version: PROJECT VERSION\n"
   "Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: EMAIL@ADDRESS\n"
   "POT-Creation-Date: 2012-09-24 03:36+0800\n"
   "PO-Revision-Date: 2012-09-24 03:37+0800\n"
   "Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
   "Language-Team: de <LL@li.org>\n"
   "Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1)\n"
   "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
   "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
   "Generated-By: Babel 0.9.6\n"

   #: templates/baseh5.html:129
   msgid "Hello"
   msgstr "Guten Tag"
   ```
5. I run this command.

   ```
   pybabel compile -d translations
   ```

   This is what I get.

   ```
   catalog 'translations/de/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po' is marked as fuzzy, skipping
   ```
6. set this is flask

   ```
   app.config['BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE'] = 'de'
   ```

What do I get?  I get `Hello`.  Why did Flask Babel not work?  How do I deal with fuzzy?  This should have been basic.

Comment: Are you certain there are no `fuzzy` lines in your .po file? Apart from the line at the top, that is. You can force babel to compile it anyway with the `-f` flag.

Comment: where do I place that flag?  what d the command line look like?  Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 17):

You can force `pybabel compile` to compile messages marked as fuzzy with the `-f` (or `--use-fuzzy`) command line switch:

```
pybabel compile -f -d translations
```

'Fuzzy' messages are marked with a `#, fuzzy` line above the `msgid` line, and are the result of a merge where a message is deemed slightly changed from the previous version. A message marked as `fuzzy` is supposed to be looked at by a human to make sure the translation doesn't need updating, after which the human translator removes that flag.

Comment: I don't think answer fits very well. Clearly forcing the compilation is the wrong solution - instead, an explanation why there's a "weird" (empty) fuzzy message would be more useful. For example, I have no idea if i should mark it as non-fuzzy or just remove it alltogether.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: My answer *already* touches upon that. You'd remove the `#, fuzzy` line; translation tools take care of that flag for you, usually.

Answer (score 5):

As pybabel said: The catalog itself was marked as "fuzzy" (6th line). If you remove that line, you don't need the 'force' option.