# Flask babel is marking fuzzy without reason

Tags: python, flask, internationalization, translation, flask-babel

I have these 2 files:

```
msgid "Categories"
msgstr "Categories" 

msgid "Dashboard"
msgstr "Dashboard"
```

And:

```
msgid "Categories"
msgstr "Categorías"

msgid "Dashboard"
msgstr "Dashboard"
```

I don't have the "# fuzzy" line. But, executing without force, it says that is fuzzy and exit.

I have read this:

[Flask Babel - 'translations/de/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po' is marked as fuzzy, skipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555692/flask-babel-translations-de-lc-messages-messages-po-is-marked-as-fuzzy-skip)

But in that case the user contains the #, fuzzy line. I don't have that line

Response compilations says that the files are marked as fuzzy.

This is my project structure:

[image]

Project structure

¿Any new idea different from use -f?

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with my local environment.

Updated setuptools and now is working well.